# iOS broken auto layout on simulator 7.1 after segue (works on ios 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have very strange problem on ios simulator 7.1 with auto layout but on ios 8 everything works fine.

On ios simulator 7.1 when new "View Controller" was presented through segue its content becomes layout incorrectly and sometimes even moves.

Demo code on github:
https://github.com/Misterio26/iOS-7-Simulator-Bug-demo

This demo uses only interface builder, there's no hand code at all, that is why I very surprised about this bug.

To reproduce:

- use xCode 6
- run with ios simulator (7.1)
- press "Works", you will see a test screen that is aligned correctly (sometimes not), then press "Back"
- press "Bug", after screen appearance you will notice some ui movement and incorrect alignment (sometimes it shows constraints error in console log)

I log window.hasAmbiguousLayout in viewDidAppear, and it print "false" for iOS 8 and "true" for iOS 7. Looks like iOS7 creates wrong constraints for presenting view controller. I used "po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace];" and it confirmed my suggestion.

I can't belive that only I have noticed this problem.

Can someone help me to know:

Is it simulator bug or it happens on real device too? (I don't have ios 7 device, just 8, and apple doesn't allow to downgrade ios)

Or maybe it can be fixed?

Or you can only try to reproduce that window.hasAmbiguousLayout becomes "true" after segue (I think that it's very dangerous bug):

- create new iOS project in XCode6
- in IB create new View Controller with one button
- in IB create second View Controller with any content
- in IB create "show" segue from button to second view controller (command + drag from button to second view controller)
- in CODE create new class @interface CustomViewController : UIViewController
- in CODE add to CustomViewController

  ```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear hasAmbiguousLayout %@", ([window hasAmbiguousLayout] ? @"true" : @"false"));
   }
  ```
- in IB apply class CustomViewController to second view controller
- run on ios 8 and you will see "viewDidAppear hasAmbiguousLayout false"
- run on ios simulator 7.1 and you'll see "viewDidAppear hasAmbiguousLayout true"

I think it's very dangerous behavior.

Comment: Your code is too complex. You should simplify by following the advices in [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] (How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce that behavior on simpler interface with lesser constraints and elements.
I don't expect full answer how to fix it, most important for me right now is to known - is it simulator bug or real device too?

Comment: @Miserio26 Yes, the bug is present on a real device running iOS 7.

Comment: O, thanks a lot, it desides everything, then I will use old style auto resizing. It's a pity because I like autolayout but I need 7.0 support.